# Guice configure/bind best practices

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

How to configure Guice if you have layered architecture (DAO, Services, Controllers)?

It should be configured in top layer (Controllers)? Or we should configure in each layer? If so, when how to clue them together?

How about tests? How it should be?
Thanks.

Comment: I personally configure by feature because it's more efficient to have a whole feature at the same place. packages are explicit, modules are easier to config. This requires to stop thinking about "layers". You have a book package, for instance, you put your entity `Book` in there, as well as `BookService`, `BookDao`, `BookController`. And to bind everything together, you put your `BookModule` in that package too. So to answer your question, I'd refactor into feature-based layout then put a Module in each package.

Answer (score 0):

According to general practices, 
**DAO** is as light as possible and exists  to provide a connection to the DB.

The **Service layer** is there to provide logic to operate on the data sent to and from the DAO and the client.

Very often these will be bundled together into the same module, and occasionally into the same code, but you'll still see them as distinct logical entities.

So you should bind services needed into corresponding Guice module and inject into controllers, and its better to provide DAO to service implementation layer through injection.

According to testing approach, Each DAO should be tested separately on server side for its functionalities, if your Service does not perform any functionality other than logic to operate on the data sent to and from the DAO and the client.